# ¿Cuál es el origen de "pisaverde" como sinónimo de "gomoso"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, adjetivos

Estaba escuchando música al azar cuando me topé con una canción de Sara Montiel. Me gustó, así que me puse a bucear en su discografía. Hay joyas y entre ellas me encontré con [*Los Nardos*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hsanfnRjZ4), en cuya letra se dice:

> Y el **gomoso** que la ve
>   Va y le dice venga usted
>   A ponerme en la solapa
>   Lo que quiera
>
> <sub>*Los Nardos*, de Sara Montiel. [Letra completa en letras.com](https://www.letras.com/sara-montiel/1302144/)</sub>

<s>Esta palabra me sonaba de haberla oído en Colombia como sinónimo de *pijo*, por lo que me sorprendió que la dijera la cantante española en una letra claramente española (habla de la Calle Alcalá de Madrid).</s> no, la palabra en la que creía pensar es [*gomelo*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gomelo)

Tirando del hilo, veo que el DLE la recoge:

> [**gomoso, sa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JKUk6s2)
>   `Del lat. gummōsus.`
>
> 1. adj. Que tiene goma o se parece a ella.
> 2. adj. Med. Que padece gomas. U. t. c. s.
> 3. m. coloq. **pisaverde**. U. t. c. adj.
>
> > [**pisaverde**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TCBOVJh)
> >
> > 1. m. coloq. Hombre presumido y afeminado, que no conoce más ocupación que la de acicalarse, perfumarse y andar vagando todo el día en busca de galanteos.

Pero ante tamaño descubrimiento en forma de palabra tan altisonante como *pisaverde* la pregunta es: ¿cómo llegó *pisaverde* a denominar a este tipo de personas?

Comment: He leído el titular y he pensado "¿el origen de qué como sinónimo de qué?". No había oído nunca ninguna de las dos palabras. En todo caso, al final del texto parece que haces dos preguntas que podrían ir a dos entradas diferentes: una el origen de "pisaverde" como sinónimo de galán/ligón, y otra el origen de "gomoso" a partir de "goma".

Comment: @Charlie llevas razón. Es la típica curiosidad que  da pie a otra y estás tan emocionado con ellas que quieres saberlo todo en el momento. He editado para centrarme solamente en _pisaverde_, que es la parte que contestó ukemi (y así no altero el alcance de su respuesta). En unos días preguntaré por la otra :) Edito: ¡uf, tu respuesta acaba de entrar y también se centra en esta parte!

Comment: Ups, emocionado estaba yo redactando mi respuesta, que no me había dado cuenta de que @ukemi ya había respondido con lo principal.

Comment: Una nota al margen.  En Colombia gomoso y pijo no son lo mismo, por lo menos no en Antioquia (tendría que validar otras zonas). Gomoso en Colombia se refiere a la persona que al recibir algo nuevo lo usa día y noche sin parar. Ej el niño recibe una bicicleta nueva de regalo y 3 dias más tarde no hace sino montar en la bici nueva y alguien le dice **"bájese de esa bicicleta mijo, deje de ser _gomoso_ "**

Comment: @DGaleano ¡qué buena! Coincide con lo que dice el DAMER y que tenía en la [primera versión de la pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/revisions/27154/1), por lo que será aplicable a toda Colombia. Me doy cuenta que recordé mal la palabra, ¿será acaso [_gomelo_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gomelo)?

Comment: @fedorqui exacto. Gomelo si es para nosotros lo que para ustedes es pijo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues resulta que *pisaverde* es una palabra bastante antigua, siendo este su primer caso en el CORDE:

> *El paje que os dije de recados, hácele camarero, porque es anejo al oficio primero; al que ven que es un poco pisaverde, polidete, hácenle maestre-sala para que, pues él no se sabe gobernar, gobierne a los pajes; [...].*
>
> Diego Hermosilla, "Diálogo de los pajes: en que se trata de la vida que á mediados del siglo XVI llevaban en los palacios de los Señores, del galardón de sus servicios, y del modo como los Grandes se gobernaban y debieran gobernarse", 1545 (España).

Afortunadamente, Covarrubias nos ilustra en esta ocasión con el posible origen de la palabra en su diccionario de 1611:

> PISAVERDE, este nombre suelen dar al moço galã, de poco seso, que va pisando de puntillas por no rebentar el seso que lleva en los carcañales. La metafora estâ tomada del que atraviesa en algun jardin por los quadros del, que por no hollar los lazos va pisando de puntillas; o porque en los prados donde ay yerva ay humedad, y por no mojarse todo el pie van de puntillas.

Comentarios:

- Cuando habla de *carcañales* se refiere al [calcañar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6io2Q71), la extremidad del pie por la parte que cae a la pantorrilla. Afirma Covarrubias que se dice "tener el seso en los carcañales" de los mozos pisaverdes.
- Cuando habla de los cuadros de los jardines se refiere a la parte labrada en cuadro, adornada con labores de flores y hierbas.

El *Diccionario de Autoridades* recoge esta definición y también la historia de su origen del *Tesoro* de Covarrubias. Aunque la definición parece más esclarecedora:

> El mozuelo presumido de galán, holgazán, y sin empleo ni aplicación, que todo el dia se anda passeando.

Curiosas me resultan también las traducciones a otros idiomas en los diccionarios español-inglés de los siglos XVII y XVIII:

> Pisaverde. A he who goeth on his tiptoes. (Minsheu, 1617)
>   Pisaverde, a nice [Fop](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fop) that walks as if he were afraid to touch the Ground. (Stevens, 1706)

Estas traducciones recalcan aún más la idea de que un pisaverde es aquel que anda como si estuviera pisando por un verde y húmedo jardín de flores.

Por último, mencionar que Corominas también cita a Covarrubias en su *Breve diccionario etimológico* (tercera edición, 1973):

> *Pisaverde*, 1570-80, porque anda de puntillas, como el que atraviesa los cuadros de un jardín.

Comment: Qué bueno cuando habla de _polidete_. Esta palabra no aparece en el DLE, pero sí [_polido_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TWz23tD). A lo mejor es etimología-ficción, ¿pero no te parece que incluso se podría ver esta forma de andar como la propia de alguien que actúa a escondidas? Me viene a la mente la imagen de un amante cruzando el jardín a hurtadillas por la noche para ver a la dama...

Comment: @fedorqui: "polidete" sería como "guapete", no está en el diccionario pero sabemos que es un diminutivo afectuoso. Ciertamente podría verse como dices, pero por lo que he leído el pisaverde no actuaría a escondidas. En ningún documento se menciona el carácter furtivo de las actividades del pisaverde, sino simplemente que su modo habitual de andar es así.

Answer (score 1):

Según el Tesoro de Covarrubias, la etimología de *pisaverde* es así (de *pisar* + *verde*):

> **pisaverde:**
>
> «Este nombre suelen dar al mozo galán, de poco seso, que va pisando de puntillas por no reventar el seso que lleva en los carcañales. La metáfora está tomada del que atraviesa en algún jardín por los cuadros de él, que por no hollar los lazos va pisando de puntillas; o porque en los prados, donde hay hierba hay humedad, y por no mojarse todo el pie van de puntillas».
>
> - [*Tesoro de la lengua castellana o española*](http://fondosdigitales.us.es/fondos/libros/765/1217/tesoro-de-la-lengua-castellana-o-espanola/),  Sebastián de Covarrubias (1611) (p.1217)