# ¿Por qué se llama "gomoso" al hombre presumido y afeminado?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, adjetivos

En la canción [*Los Nardos*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hsanfnRjZ4) de Sara Montiel me encontré con:

> Y el **gomoso** que la ve
>   Va y le dice venga usted
>   A ponerme en la solapa
>   Lo que quiera
>
> <sub>*Los Nardos*, de Sara Montiel. [Letra completa en letras.com](https://www.letras.com/sara-montiel/1302144/)</sub>

Tirando del hilo, vi que el DLE la recoge:

> [**gomoso, sa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JKUk6s2)
>   `Del lat. gummōsus.`
>
> 1. adj. Que tiene goma o se parece a ella.
> 2. adj. Med. Que padece gomas. U. t. c. s.
> 3. m. coloq. **pisaverde**. U. t. c. adj.

Sobre *pisaverde* en [*¿Cuál es el origen de “pisaverde” como sinónimo de “gomoso”?*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27157/1674) se explicó su origen y uso. Por tanto, ahora me centraré en *gomoso*.

De este, el DAMER nos indica:

> [**gomoso, -a.**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gomoso)
>
> I.    1.  adj/sust. Co. Referido a persona, que tiene alguna goma o afición excesiva por algo. pop.
>   II. 1.  adj. Gu, Ho, ES, Ni. Referido a persona, que padece goma, resaca.
>   III.    1.  adj. PR. Referido a una sustancia, pegajosa, pringosa.

En definitiva, tanto *gomoso* como *pisaverde* son adjetivos para definir de forma algo peyorativa a un galán o más bien un ligón.

Sin embargo, la pregunta es obvia: ¿por qué de *goma* se pasó a *gomoso*? Es decir, ¿qué tiene la goma que dé lugar a calificar a alguien así? ¿Será el andar que tendría alguien cuyos zapatos son de goma y va, digamos, andando de forma un tanto peculiar, como rebotando en el suelo?

Comment: Igual entre los muchos significados de [goma](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=goma) en el DAMER encuentras algo que te encaje.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El término gomoso referente a un sujeto, es un casticismo madrileño muy empleado desde finales del XIX hasta mediados del XX. Se refiere a un hombre muy arreglado, con el pelo engominado y brillante, relamido, de punta en blanco. Las clase populares se burlaban de este tipo de chicos, y cuando alguien se arreglaba mucho, en torno de burla, se le decía que parecía un gomoso, de la esencia de la goma. Más arriba nombran una canción que no es de Sara Montiel, sino el pasacalle de la revista musical Las leandras:-y el gomoso que la ve, va y le dice venga usted a ponerme en la solapa lo que quiera...Pues eran los clientes más habituales, ya que eran chicos con dinero, a la moda, de buena familia. En esta misma obra, en el dúo de la florista y su hombre, este se pone celoso al verla hablar con un gomoso: -dile al gomoso que sea afanoso, que se cerró el portal, y ella le dice que él toma varas y conviene como cliente. Varas se refiere que no compra flores sueltas, sino en varas, por lo que es buen cliente. Así que es un término que no aparece en el diccionario, pues es popular, y procede de la calle, y sobre todo divulgado por el teatro en sainetes y zarzuelas chicas.

Answer (score 3):

¿Quizás por usar [**gomina**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JKReih5)

> De goma e -ina.
>   1. f. Fijador del cabello.

para acicalarse?

La entrada más antigua  del **CORDE** que encuentro para esa acepción es de 1872:

> La que con más modestia que justicia se llama á sí propia la buena sociedad, siempre dispuesta á buscar y recoger el mérito cuando éste se halla ya en disposicion de servirla de adorno, encontró un nuevo motivo para solicitarle y atraerle, y Cervántes llegó á ser un pollo verdaderamente fashionable, un **gomoso** con ménos goma que otros, no lo niego, pero digno de figurar á la cabeza de nuestra high life.  (Carlos Coello, Cuentos inverosímiles)

La entrada más antigua que he encontrado en un **diccionario** es en el de Zerolo (1895): 


[image]

Answer (score 2):

En el "Inventario general de insultos" de Celdrán Gomáriz (1995) se recoge (negrita mías):

> **Gomoso**
>   Pisaverde, petimetre, currutaco; lechuguino excesivamente baboso con las mujeres. **Deriva de
>   "goma", en su acepción de "laca, maque",** de donde también se dijo "maqueado", **por el peinado tratado
>   con esa substancia que se empezó a utilizar en España durante la segunda mitad del siglo pasado, y del
>   que abusaron los elegantes del momento**. Su equivalente actual es el tipo engominado que se embadurna la cabeza con fijador. En la zarzuela del maestro Francisco Alonso, Las Leandras, se utiliza así el término, que no debía tener por entonces demasiada vida:
>
> "Y el gomoso que la ve
>   va y le dice: Venga usté
>   a ponerme en la solapa
>   lo que quiera; ..."

Answer (score 1):

Creo que venga del uso de goma en la ropa para que quede más estirada... Un gomoso es una persona que seria presumido y por ello usaria ropa con goma...